# Why are we not considering the transpositions like $(23)$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

A transposition $(m k)$ on $n$ **identical** objects is defined as the **operation in which the objects in the positions $m$ and $k$ are to be interchanged leaving all the other objects where they are**.
In the case of symmetric group $S_n$ of degree $n$ (finite), there are $n!$ such invariant permutations of $n$ identical objects. The [book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afuSs.jpg) says that, $S_n$ can be generated by the $n-1$ transpositions $(12),(13), \ldots,(1 n)$.*Why are we not considering the transpositions like $(23)$? Is it because $(23)$ can be generated by $(23)=(12)(13)(12)$?*

Comment: Yes, the answer you gave yourself is correct. You could of course include it, but that would make the generating set unnecessarily large and more complicated.

Comment: Cyclic groups are a good example in this context. They are just generated by **one** element. So there is no need to consider more elements (see the last sentence in the answer below, for the cyclic group $\Bbb Z$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. That's the *entire point*.  A generating set is just a set of elements that can be used to create all the rest using the group law.
There are many other generating sets for $S_n$ besides $(12), (13), \ldots, (1n)$. See Section $2$ [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf) for many other choices of generating sets, such as $(12)$ and $(12\ldots n)$.

If I say $\mathbf Z$ is generated by $1$, would you object that I am not mentioning $2$ or $3$ or $-5679$?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, yes. Note that you could choose other subsets of transpositions that generate $S_n$ too: the book is simply saying that the set of $n-1$ transpositions $\{ (1i), 1 < i \leq n\}$ is ***a*** set of generators of $S_n$.